# What is the name for making stuff up from texts?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen done with various "holy" books etc., where by a relationship between alphabet/characters/number of occurrences of alphabet/word etc are related to some new scientific breakthrough/prediction you name it is pointed out or correlated with.

I considered charlatanism but that assumes some sort of gain is obtained, in the case I am looking for, it seems as if it is hobby/trolling.

I think some academic proved that given any text, one can make up some rules that would relate/map the text to any arbitrary text, but I can not remember the name ( if there was one coined for the process).

Edit: As an example consider this: in book X, Section Y, letter F has appeared 9 times, in Periodic table F is for fluorine and appears at the 9th spot! All behold the miracles of book x of religion z.

I did not want to pick on a specific religion, therefore x,y,z, but this type of conjuring can be applied to any book x of any religion z.

Edit: sophistry seems to be the too broad.

Comment: I can't think of any term with this exact range right now. There are [Bible codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code) and other theories that hold that well-known works like those of [Shakespeare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baconian_theory_of_Shakespeare_authorship#Baconian_cryptology) contain messages in cypher form. In relation to Hebrew specifically, there is [gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) (which is a type of numerology). The academic field relating to analysis like you mention in the last sentence is cryptography.

Comment: @sumelic : thank you, gematria is way too specific and on it's own can not be used to justify some mysticism, still requires somebody to add additional story to relate two texts. cryptography is a strech, as the both texts are plain text and the aim is to make up some human connection between the two.

Comment: @sumelic : Yes almost Bible codes, but that is too specific to Bible, this type of hoodwinkery is common in all the religions. e.g. Length of a passage matches some bozo's birth date , etc. of course the same bozo might be want to be portrayed as either evil or god sent, depending on the motivation of conjurer.

Comment: Is this about [Quantitative Textual Analysis](https://dhminor.stanford.edu/literary-text-mining-introduction-quantitative-textual-analysis) as it relates to [Authorship Attribution?](http://www.aicbt.com/authorship-attribution/online-software/)

Comment: What do you mean by saying the aim is to make a human connection? You started out by mentioning alphabets and characters, and counting the number of times things like this occur, and you say Bible codes seem relevant. If you think cryptography is not relevant because it mainly deals with ciphers, perhaps [steganography] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) is more like what you're thinking of. Wikipedia seems to just use the cover term [Hidden Messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_message).

Comment: Is it [*apophenia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers : No, that is an actual thing, what I am after is being made up.

Comment: @sumelic : I add an example to my post

Comment: Generically, it's [*flim-flammery*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flimflammery), *deception, fraud, bunco, stratagem, falsification, humbug, forgery, swindle, subterfuge, skullduggery, hoax...* I doubt there's a specific term for spuriously involving *various "holy" books etc.* in such activities, but I stand ready to be enlightened.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : I drop the involving various holy books requirement, I am going through your suggested words, they  look promising.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Humbugerrism seems close

Comment: @Arjang: usually we say [humbuggery](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humbuggery).

Comment: Kabbala or biblical numerology?   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_numerology

Comment: I would say it's akin to numerology.

Comment: @HotLicks : it is not just about numbers, it is relating things in a way to support the final argument.

Comment: @Arjang - I said *akin* to numerology.

Comment: 'Sophistry' is **very** broad. I would not have guessed that 'sophistry' was even close to the word you were after. It applies to "Specious but fallacious reasoning; employment of arguments which are intentionally deceptive." And so to any reasoning or argumentation of those types. There is no necessary connection with **books** at all.

Comment: @JEL :havent found a word that matches, that is as close I have got so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eisegesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisegesis) is the term used for reading your own preconceived notions into the text. It is contrasted with [exegesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exegesis), which relates to an understanding of the text itself.

Comment: Yes This is it!

Answer (score 3):

The general term for using books, especially sacred books, for divining answers to questions that they do not explicitly address—by means of some sort of numerological analysis, picking a word or phrase or passage at random, etc.—is ***[bibliomancy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bibliomancy).***

OED cites an 1864 piece from *Notes & Queries:*

> Bibliomancy or Divination by Books, was known to the ancients under the appellation of Sortes Homericæ and Sortes Virgilianæ. The practice was to take up the works of Homer and Virgil, and to consider the first verse that presented itself as a prognostication of future events.

Comment: That's too specific for what the OP is talking about. The link defines bilbiomancy as "Divination by interpretation of a passage chosen at random from a book, especially the Bible." But in cases like the OP is talking about, people often don't choose the passage at random; they cherry-pick it to find something that seems relevant to some other fact or future event.

Comment: @sumelic : yes, you are correct, I like the word though, I need to generalise it to not to be bible specific. something like stuffomancy, using anything for divination!

Comment: @Arjang: as this answer says, it's not specific to the Christian Bible. The root "biblio-" often just means "relating to books."

Comment: @Arjang The *bibl* in *bibliomancy* is just Greek for book, βίβλος; cf. *bibliography* and various Romance language terms for *library.* It does not specifically denote the anthology that Christians call in effect *THE* book.

Answer (score 2):

The terms for divination of the sort you describe include (along with *bibliomancy* as mentioned in an earlier answer) these:

> **stichomancy**, *n.*
>   *rare*<sup>—1</sup>.
>   Divination by lines of verse in books taken at hazard.

(From the *OED Online*. The "*rare*<sup>—1</sup>" indicates the term is attested only once.)

> **rhapsodomancy**, *n.*
>   A form of divination in which the first line seen upon opening a book, originally of poetry, at random is taken to be prophetic.

(op. cit.)

While these do not *inherently* denote that the practitioner is a fraud and the practice a charade, that additional sense could be added with an adjective:

> His *rigged* rhapsodomancy (*rhap-sodom-ancy* with the infix set off as it should be, in my estimation) sought not for his personal gain, but rather provided him only a private and cynical amusement at the folly of the dupes who took his pastime for genuine prophecy.
>
> —*Ewart MacGonicle*

Comment: rhapsodomancy!! thank you for that, I didnt even fathom there is a word for that!

Comment: This is also called [Sortes Biblicae](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195046458.001.0001/acref-9780195046458-e-0697) (or sortes Vergilanae or whatever). But I don't think it is what OP has in mind; rather the practitioners purport to find a deliberate code hidden in the text. This flares up from time to time; there was an outbreak around teh time of *The Da Vinci Code*.